# Add a number to the item in a collection

Tags: .net

How do I add a number to the item in a collection?

The collection:

```
Public Property MyCol As ObservableCollection(of Item)
```

Item:

```
Public Class Item
    Public Property ID as Long
    Public Property Count as Double
End Class
```

And let's say this is my collection (ID, Count)

- 1, 500
- 2, 300
- 3, 400

...and I want to add 100 to the Item with ID=2.
How do I do it?

Comment: You might want to look into using a `Dictionary<K,V>` instead of a collection. Although, it seems .NET does not provide an observable version.

Comment: UI binds to this collection and as you mentioned I need an observable version of it.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear, so I'm going to answer both of my interpretations.

If you're trying to add an item at a specific index of 2:

C#

```
MyCol.InsertItem(2, new Item());
```

VB.Net

```
MyCol.InsertItem(2, new Item())
```

This inserts an item at the specified index, making all the subsequent items in the collection have their index altered by 1. For more information, here's the MSDN article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms654928(v=vs.110).aspx

If you're trying to add 100 to the item at index 2:

C#

```
MyCol[2].Count += 100;
```

VB.Net

```
MyCol[2].Count += 100
```

This grabs the item at the index of 2, and adds 100 to the Count property on that object.

Comment: He doesn't want the second index. He wants to change the value of the item with a specific id.

Comment: I want to change the number (Count property of the Item) with a specific ID -> Example: "Find an Item that has ID of 2 and add 100 to its Count property"

Answer (score 0):

I think this would work:

```
Dim MyItem As Item = MyCol.Where(Function(x) x = 2).FirstOrDefault
MyItem.Count = MyItem.Count + 100
```